# Prevent Repetitive KeyDown Code From Running (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

If you hold down the key in a KeyDown Sub, it repeats the code until it is released.
Is there any way to prevent the code from continuously running and keep it so that it only runs once? Thanks.

Comment: On KeyDown, you could store, say, the KeyCode in a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), and remove it on KeyUp. Before doing anything in the KeyDown handler, check if it is already in the HashSet and if it is then do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle more than one key events to do that. For example

```
Public Class Form1

    Private keyHolding As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If Not keyHolding Then
            Label1.Text &= "Keydown event detected "
            keyHolding = True

            'Place the code that you want to run only once in the key down event here...
        Else
            Label1.Text &= "User is holding the key down "

            'Place the code that you want to run continuously in the key down event here...
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        Label1.Text &= "KeyUp event detected "
        keyHolding = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Just keep in mind that this approach is good for standard windows forms applications. If you are developing a game, for example, then this approach will cause various problems and there are better solutions either via native API calls or some game developing framework.

Hope this helps.